# Static light keeps moving when objects are translated

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

Why does my light move with my camera? in my draw scene function I set my light source position, then I call my matrix, translate the "camera", then a sphere, and after two cubes. When I move the camera around along with the first cube, the light source moves with it...

```
 function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    //currentProgram = perFragmentProgram;
    currentProgram = perVertexProgram;
    gl.useProgram(currentProgram);

    gl.uniform3f(
        currentProgram.ambientColorUniform,
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientR").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientG").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientB").value)
    );

    gl.uniform3f(
         currentProgram.pointLightingLocationUniform,
         parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionX").value),
         parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionY").value),
         parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionZ").value)
    );

    gl.uniform3f(
        currentProgram.pointLightingColorUniform,
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("pointR").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("pointG").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("pointB").value)
    );

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    //Camera
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-xPos, -yPos, -10]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(180), [0, 1, 0]);

    //Sphere
    mvPushMatrix();
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(moonAngle), [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [5, 0, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, moonVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, moonVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexIndexBuffer);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    mvPopMatrix();

    //Cube 1
    object.render(xPos, yPos);

    //Cube 2
    object2.render(0, 5);
}
```

And my shaders look like this.

```
<script id="per-vertex-lighting-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

void main(void) {
    vec4 fragmentColor;
    fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, fragmentColor.a);
}
</script>

<script id="per-vertex-lighting-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

uniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;
uniform vec3 uPointLightingColor;

uniform bool uUseLighting;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

void main(void) {
    vec4 mvPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * mvPosition;


    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uPointLightingLocation - mvPosition.xyz);

    vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
    float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, lightDirection), 0.0);

    vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uPointLightingColor * directionalLightWeighting;

}
</script>
```

What can I do to stop the light from being moved around so its static

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but are those point light calculations?  They look like directional calculations.  It doesn't look like you ever use `lightPositionX/Y/Z` in either your vert or frag shader.

Comment: I'm not sure... i'm terribly new to glsl.. How would I change the uPointLightLocation to calculate the position rather than direction

Comment: `uPointLightingLocation` must be in *eye space*, matching `transformedNormal` which you're comparing it to. Multiply `lightPosition` (assuming it's in world space) by the view/camera matrix before passing it in.

Comment: How do I seperate the view matrix from uMVMatrix? I'm sorry i'm really new to this, is there any way you can edit the code above so I can see exactly what you mean? I think the only way for me to learn is to see it @jozxyqk

Answer (score 1):

`uPointLightingLocation` must be in *eye space*, matching `transformedNormal` which you're comparing it to with the dot product.

Multiply `lightPosition` (assuming it's in world space) by the *view*/*camera* matrix. It'll be cheaper to do this outside the shader as the value does not change during the render.

The *view* matrix already exists in your code mid-way through the *model-view* construction.
The `//Camera` block is the *view* and the `//Sphere` block multiplies in the *model* transform. To extract just the *view*, copy `mvMatrix` between your `Camera` and `Sphere` transform blocks (or just transform the light then and there).

```
//untested, but something along these lines
var worldSpaceLight = vec4.fromValues( //not sure which lib your using
     parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionX").value),
     parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionY").value),
     parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionZ").value),
     1.0
);
...
//Camera
...
var eyeSpaceLight = vec4.create();
vec4.transformMat4(eyeSpaceLight, worldSpaceLight, mvMatrix);
gl.uniform3f(currentProgram.pointLightingLocationUniform, eyeSpaceLight);
//Sphere
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me figure it out!